# Complicated factorial expression simplification

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have 
$$\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{j}\binom{n-k-j}{i}$$
I have it now simplified to 
$$\frac{n!}{i!j!k!(n-k-j-i)!}$$
I was under the impression that the multinomial number was 
$$\frac{n!}{i!j!k!}=\binom{n}{i,j,k}$$
and it was under the condition that $i+j+k=n$.
How can I rewrite my expression as a multinomial?

Comment: I am not familiar with this notation, but this would be $n\choose i,j,k,n-i-j-k$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\binom{n}{i,j,k}$ with $i+j+k=n$ is a **trinomial** coefficient, just one kind of multinomial coefficient.

Your expression is a **tetranomial** coefficient, because you have four factorials downstairs and $$i+j+k+(n-k-j-i)=n$$

Thus, it can be expressed as $$\binom{n}{i,\ j,\ k,\ n-k-j-i}$$

Comment: I've edited my answer to use "coefficient" more consistently. Strictly speaking a trinomial is an expression of the form $x+y+z$ in an algebraic context, and the trinomial _coefficients_ are the used in taking it to non-negative integer powers.

Answer (score 5):

If $i + j + k = n$, then $n - k - j - i = 0$.  Thus, 
$$\frac{n!}{i!j!k!(n - k - j - i)!} = \frac{n!}{i!j!k!0!} = \frac{n!}{i!j!k!}$$ since $0! = 1$.  If $i + j + k < n$, then the multinomial is an expression in more than three variables, in which case the expression you obtained for $\binom{n}{k}\binom{n - k}{j}\binom{n - k - j}{i}$ would only be a multinomial coefficient if there were exactly four variables.

Comment: Please explain the downvote.  What flaw do you see with my answer?

Comment: (1) You did not answer the question. (2) You did not correct the mistaken impression of the original poster that all multinomials are trinomials, which was the root of his confusion.

Comment: @AndrewWoods  Thanks for your response.  I have edited my answer.  The way I interpreted the question was that $i + j + k \leq n$.  If equality holds, then it is a trinomial and $(n - k - j - i)! = 0! = 1$.  If $i + j + k < n$, then there are additional terms in the denominator of the multinomial coefficient.  If there are exactly four terms in the denominator of the multinomial, then it is a tetranomial.

Comment: Every $m$-nomial coefficient can be expressed as a $m+1$-nomial coefficient by placing an extra $0!$ in the denominator. For example the binomial $\binom73\equiv\binom7{3,4}$ can be written as $\binom7{3,4,0},\ \binom7{3,4,0,0},$ etc. So provided that the binomial coefficients at the top of the page are all non-zero, so that the manipulations make sense, it should be fine to call the result a tetranomial coefficient, just as $\binom22\equiv\binom2{2,0}$ is a binomial coefficient.